# Missing files after using cx_freeze, exe runs in Anaconda prompt but not in cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, anaconda, cx-freeze

I ran into some problems with using `cx_freeze` to create executables from python code. The built executables run from the Anaconda prompt, but when run in windows cmd (or via click on the .exe) the program exits with an error message related to the requests package.

Here is a minimal working example. First, the script that will be frozen: `main.py`

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('https://github.com/')

print(r.text)
```

Secondly, the setup script for `cx_freeze`: `setup.py`

```py
import cx_Freeze

build_exe_options = {
        "includes": [],
        'include_files': [],
        'excludes' : [],
        'packages' : []
           }

base = None

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable('main.py',
                                    base=base)]

cx_Freeze.setup(name = "MWE",
                options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
                executables = executables)
```

Here is the problem:

1. Running `main.py` in python works as expected
2. Building the executable via `python setup.py build` works fine
3. Running the resulting `main.exe` in the Anaconda prompt works as expected
4. Running `main.exe` in the windows cmd (or starting via mouse-click) exits with the following error message:

   ```py
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "P:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 40, in run
       module.run()
     File "P:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 23, in run
       exec(code, {'__name__': '__main__'})
     File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
       r = requests.get('https://github.com/')
     File "P:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
       return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     File "P:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
       return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     File "P:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
     File "P:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
     File "P:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
       raise SSLError(e, request=request)
   requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded
   with url: / (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
   ```

After digging through related issues it seems the problem is that some DLLs are not copied into the build-folder of the application, such that these files cannot be found by the application. What I tried without positive result:

1. Played with the `includes` and `packages` options in the setup script to include certain packages (as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53323828/11011452))
2. Manually copied `libssl` and `libcrypto` to the build-folder (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53333922/11011452) and [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273))
3. Copied the same files via the `include_files` option in the setup script
4. Added `(requests.certs.where(),'cacert.pem')` to `include_files` and `os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "cacert.pem")` to `setup.py` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224335/11011452) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25239701/11011452)

Does anyone know how to avoid this issue? Does anyone know how to find out which files exactly are missing, such that they can be copied to the application folder? I ran into the same problem with other packages, not only `requests`.

Comment: I don't know a lot about `cx_freeze` but I was interested in the problem: when googling I found that there seem to be a few issues like yours with cx_freeze version 5.x. What version are you using? Your example works perfectly fine for me (starting it by double-clicking the exe and from Windows CMD both work), no workarounds required at all (using `cx_freeze` version 6.0).

Comment: Interesting. That defeats the purpose of my MWE... I'm also on `cx_freeze` 6.0 and set up a whole new conda env in python 3.7 to test this. So all packages are up to date. Did my example run for you without any adjustments? Are you using Anaconda or a different python environment?

Comment: I used a fresh conda env with Python 3.7 I did have to make one adjustment but didn't mention it since it seemed unrelated: when I ran your MWE I got `ImportError: No module named 'queue'` which I resolved by changing the `build_exe_options` in your `setup.py` to include `'packages' : ["multiprocessing"]` (taken from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768570/importerror-no-module-named-queue-while-running-my-app-freezed-with-cx-freeze)

Comment: Here's a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/zi5qDm9V) of my dependencies for your MWE in case you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get that error. I will still try whether your solution works for me. Will report back.